# Toggle Background/Foreground Modes

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm trying to make it so that when you press the power button to turn off the android, my app goes into background mode. When you press the power button to turn on the android, my app should go into foreground mode.

The error I get is:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent {
>   act=android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON flg=0x50000010 }

The error comes from the intent with FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Here's the MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
            filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
            BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new ScreenReceiver(MainActivity.this, this);
            registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

            moveTaskToBack(true);
        }
    }
```

Here's the BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    MainActivity mainAct;
    Context ctx;
    public ScreenReceiver(MainActivity act, Context con) {
        mainAct = act;
        ctx = con;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            mainAct.moveTaskToBack(true);
            System.out.println("OFF");
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            Intent i = new Intent(ctx, ScreenReceiver.class);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            mainAct.startActivity(i);
            System.out.println("ON");
        }
    }

}
```

I'm using code from the following tutorial:

https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was passing ScreenReceiver.class instead of MainActivity.class into the intent. Here's the corrected version:

```
public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    MainActivity mainAct;
    Context ctx;
    public ScreenReceiver(MainActivity act, Context con) {
        mainAct = act;
        ctx = con;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            mainAct.moveTaskToBack(true);
            System.out.println("OFF");
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            Intent i = new Intent(ctx, MainActivity.class);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            mainAct.startActivity(i);
            System.out.println("ON");
        }
    }

}
```